# how do i subset many variable in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, subset, subset-sum

i want to ask how do i subset many data from 5k variable.

i have a 500k data frame, the data was groceries data (super market). i want to subset all the reciept ID, but the ID is too many (about 24,5 k). i want ro find the total price of each reciept. How do i subset those ID without manual typing?

the data i use :
[this is my data looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X15zW.png)
i want to subset all of the InvoiceID and count each price. then i want to convert it to data frame.

i already try to use "for" function, but it keeps looping. i also use `dplyr` package in R

the code i use :

```r
test = data %>%
  group_by(InvoiceNo)%>%
  dplyr::summarise(n= n())

bon = test$InvoiceNo

result = for (i in bon){
  data = subset(data, subset = InvoiceNo == i)
  print(sum(data$Price_Total))
}

test =  data.frame("test" = bon,
                   "wiw" = result)
```

i want to make a plot out of the total of each reciept.
how should i subset it? or what package should i use ?
thankyouu

Comment: You may use `split` i.e. `split(data, data$InvoiceNo)`

Comment: Okayy, i already try it. thanks for helping. are there any another way to subset it??

Comment: Hey there! As you already mentioned your data is pretty large, you can provide the head of your dput next time.

Answer (score 0):

You’re on the right track with `group_by(InvoiceNo) %>% summarize()`. Since you want to sum up price within each InvoiceNo, you would just put that within the call to `summarize()`:

```
test = data %>%
  group_by(InvoiceNo)%>%
  summarise(Price_Total = sum(Price_Total))
```

Comment: hello, i already try it. thankyouu for your answer. i try it and i found new way to sum it all round. i want to calculate total of each reciept, and maybe make a box plot out of it.

sorry i forgot to add "each" in the question, but it's a good answerr. thankyouu

Comment: Yes, the code I provided will give you the total for each receipt. You can then pass the result to ggplot to get a boxplot: `ggplot(test) + geom_boxplot(aes(Price_Total))`

Comment: i try the code, but the boxplot isn't come out. `test` is a df 1x1. the boxplot didn't came out...

Comment: Run *only* the code I provided - don’t combine it with your original code. If that doesn’t work, please update your question with your data (use dput() or the reprex package) and output.